# Django cannot find a view

Tags: django

I am new to Django
I am trying to call a python function/view on the click of a submit button.

I have made the necessary changes to tell the url file where to look at.

This is the urls.py of my site and I am concerned with polls app.

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

This is the urls.py of polls app.

```
urlpatterns = [
# ex: /polls/
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
# ex: /polls/5/
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
# ex: /polls/5/results
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
# ex: /polls/5/vote
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),

# ex: /test/
url('/test/$', views.test, name='test'),
]
```

I want to call a function called test when submit button is clicked.

Part of index.html

```
<form action="/polls/test/" method="get">  
Find: <input type="text" name="" size="35">
<input type="submit" value="Add Stuff">
</form>
```

Now, when click of this button if get error stating Django tried these URL and cannot find it.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/test/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, in this order: 

patterns, in this order:

^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$ [name='results']
^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
^polls/ /test/$ [name='test']
^admin/

 The current URL, polls/test/, didn't match any of these.
```

Am I missing something very obvious here?
I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the leading `/` from your test url. You should also add a `^` at the beginning of the regex, so that it matches `test` but not `xtest`.

```
url('^test/$', views.test, name='test'),
```

As an aside, you can use the [url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to prevent having to hardcode the url in your template.

```
<form action="{% url 'test' %}" method="get">
```